# Getting info of shared items from Facebook

Tags: iphone, facebook, ipad

Hi I am developing a app for iPhone in which I have incorporated FB framework. What I have to do is I need to fetch the private messages from a logged in user's account. Along with the messages I have to handle the item such as video/link/photo shared with that message. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to ask the user for permission(via the FB api) to access the private messages.

Once you get the content, you'll have to handle the items yourself, if it's a photo, show it in an imageview, etc.

Comment: Thanks Owook. To show the photo, I should have the link to that image. Thats what I am asking. How to get video/photo/link attached to the messages?